Way to limit memory usage on a R version 4.0+ windows session?
Is there a way to set a limit on the memory usage for a windows R session with R version 4.0 and above?  I have found post regarding setting a limit on R 3.6.3 and below by using a command line flag: --max-mem-size which can set the initial limit of the R session.  However I believe this option is removed from R version 4.0.  So if there is an alternative equivalent to setting the command line flag: --max-mem-size?
Tested setting the same command line flag, but I am not able to verify with memory.limit() command as it was disabled in the R version 4 and up.

It should work by editing the .Renviron file, although this is not a per-instance method like the command line flag. Maybe you find something helpful in this discussion.

You should be able to use the environmental variable R_MAX_MEM_SIZE, further documented here. Calls to memory.limit() are only able to increase memory, not limit it, so it wouldn't be as relevant for your usecase.

Does this work for R 4+?  I am seeing this post that it is disabled in R 4+.  https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/2021/08/31    Also I am unable to call memory.limit() in R4+.  is there another way to check memory within R?   For example, I am getting follow error in R 4.2 when I run memory.limit() : Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is no longer supported
